# What does “hype job” mean?

Tags: meaning

There was the following passage in February 25 Washington Post Style section article that came under the headline, “The heights of Hype”:

> “Mr. (Neely) Tucker uses historical documents and interviews to make a
>   strong case that the idea of the book as a long-lost sequel is at best
>   **a hype job**, and at worst a literary deception.

I found no source of the definition of this word in Google Search, but found one example of a sentence using the word, “hype job,” which was the quote from www.boxingnews24.com （2014/09/22）:

> "By Robert “Big Moe” Elmore: I don't believe no fighter is **a hype job**
>   regardless of how the media builds them up ... Is he a mixed bag
>   (meaning he can brawl, box, has footwork, has good offense defense,
>   volume puncher etc)."

Google Ngram shows that the word emerged in 1967, and its usage has been plummeting to 0.0000000148% level after peaking at 0.0000000333 in 1991.

What does “hype job” mean? What kind of job is it like?

Comment: A "hype job" is simply a situation where the actor delivers a bunch of hype.  Where "hype" is exaggeration and window-dressing.  Many/most politicians are experts at "hype jobs", as are many TV network commentators.  A "publicity agent" for, say, an author is presumably skilled at "hype jobs".

Comment: *Hype job* isn't a set phrase; it's *hype* plus *job* in the sense of a task or a piece of work that is done. Just as my car's *paint job* refers to the work and results of painting it, and a *hatchet job* is a particular slander (metaphorically, as if attacking someone with a hatchet), a *hype job* is the work someone has done to hype something up.

Comment: @Hot Licks. It sounds like a cosmetic job to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both Hot Licks and choster say (in comments above), a "hype job" is simply a production, promotion, or other undertaking characterized by *hype*. The emphasis is on *hype*, and it is an unusual word.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) presents five separate entries for hype, and is noncommittal about the word's origin in all but one of the five cases:

> **hype** *n* [by shortening and alter. fr. *hypodermic*] (1924) **1** *slang* **:** a narcotics addict **2** *slang* **:** HYPODERMIC
>
> **hype** *vt* **hyped; hyping** (1938) **1 :** STIMULATE, ENLIVEN‚ usu. used with *up* {hyping herself up for the game} 2 : INCREASE
>
> **hype** *vt* **hyped; hyping** [origin unknown]  (ca. 1931) 1 : PUT ON , DECEIVE 2 : to promote or publicize extravagantly {*hyping* this fall's  TV lineup}
>
> **hype** *n* (1955) DECEPTION, PUT-ON 2 : PUBLICITY; *esp* : promotional publicity of an extravagant or contrived kind {all the *hype* before the boxing match}
>
> **hype** *adj.* (1989) *slang* **:** EXCELLENT, COOL

In the early 1970s, when I first encountered *hype* being used in the sense of promotional buildup, I thought that the term was simply a shortening of *hyperbole* (which MW traces to the fifteenth century with the meaning "extravagant exaggeration"). But slang dictionaries differ on this point.

From Harold Wentworth and Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1961):

> **hyped-up** *adj*. Artificial, phony, as though produced by a hypodermic injection of a stimulant. {Citation from 1950 omitted.] See **hopped-up** [which the dictionary defines as "Under the influence of narcotics; drugged").

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1994) has this:

> **hype 1** ***v*** *by 1937* To blatantly promote [citations omitted] **2** ***n*** Advertising or promotion, esp of a blatant sort [citation omitted] **3** ***v*** *by 1914* To trick; deceive; originally, to short-change **4** ***v*** *by 1938* =HYPE UP  {origin unknown, perhaps related to *hyper*, "hustle," of obscure origin, found from the mid-1800s; recent advertising and public relations senses probably influenced by *hype* [in the sense of "hypodermic needle"] as suggesting supernormal energy, excitement, etc, and by *hyper* and *hyperbole*; sense 4 supported by a 1914 glossary: "Hyper, current among money-changer. A flim-flammer"}

In the quotation from the *Washington Post*, "hype job" carries the idea of being mostly or entirely fluff or hot air emitted for the purpose of ringing up sales for an undeserving book. Interestingly, the word *job* in this instance refers to the book (in much the same way as the word *job* in "hatchet job" refers to a hostile review or exposé), and not to the job of producing the "hype job" (or in the corresponding example, the "hatchet job") nor to the person or persons who took on that job.